# Remove field from mongodb document with mongoose and axios

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios

I'm trying to delete a field in a mongodb document with mongoose and then axios on the front end. I have the route working when I use it in postman - it'll delete the field no problem, but when I try to hook it up to axios in the front end it won't work. I don't get an error or anything. Any help is much appreciated. Below is my code.

The default route is /billet so the route for this would be /billet/person/{id}

```js
router.put("/person/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const updatedBillet = await Billet.findOneAndUpdate(
      req.params.id,
      { $unset: { person: "" } },
      { new: true }
    );
    res.status(200).json(updatedBillet);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

```js
const handleRemovePerson = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await axios.put(`/billet/person/${id}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Also below are requested pictures of the request working in postman. Before is the original return when doing a get, and after is the return after running the put to remove the person field.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: Add a console in your back-end router handler to see if you are getting the request.

Comment: I did and it's getting the id which is all it should need.

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot of the working request in Postman? Please also add `console.log("ID", JSON.stringify(id))` in your frontend app and include the results

Comment: I edited my post to include pics of before and after running the put. And here is the result of the console.log you requested

ID "638a4b5d011b0c90efab6754"

Comment: I also just noticed that this works with the first document in the db but none of the others. When I do the put in postman, the return is of the first document. I'm unsure why.

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed it. I needed to use findByIdAndUpdate instead of findOneAndUpdate. I thought I had previously tried that but I guess I had something changed somewhere else to cause it to not work when I tried that.